# Uploading and showing image from S3

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image through react app to s3 bucket and then receiving back the URL and showing the image on the screen.
I am able to upload the image (sort of) and get the URL back from the s3 server, but when I download it I am unable to open it - the formant is unsupported and I can't use the img tag to show it on the webpage. I guess that it is something to do with conversation to base64 but I can't figure out why it is not working.

The frontend(React) is:

```
const uploadImageToBucket = async (image) => {
    console.log("fff",image)
 

       let image_location
        try {
            const response = axios.post("http://localhost:5000/user/blogmanage/uploadimage",image)
         
            image_location = response.then((response)=>response.data.body);
            console.log("img loc", image_location)
    
            return image_location;
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    
    
    }
```

The backend(nodejs) is

```
    router.post("/blogmanage/uploadimage", async (req,res)=>{

    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: process.env["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
        secretAccessKey: process.env["AWS_SECRET_KEY"],
        region: process.env['AWS_REGION']
      });
    const BUCKET_NAME = "mrandmrseatmedia";
  
    var base64data = new Buffer.from( 'binary',req.body);
    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: "test/test2.jpg",
        Body: base64data
    }
    
    s3.upload(params, function (err,data){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
            res.status(404).json({msg:err});
        }
        else{
            const image_location = `${data.Location}`;
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
            res.status(200).json({body:image_location});
        }
        
    })
   });
```

Thanks!

Comment: `image_location` will still be a promise, how are you using it?

Comment: image location is not a problem. I get the URL as I am supposed to do.
The problem, i guesstimate, is the upload.
and per your question, image_location returns only URL which I embed in Quill' text editor

Comment: I tried to insert "manualy" the URL to an img tag, and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing and retesting and rewriting using this repo as an example
https://github.com/Jerga99/bwm-ng/blob/master/server/services/image-upload.js
It works.

The use of base64 is wrong in this case. It corrupts the file in some way. Multer library fixes it.